# Why is my async ASP.NET Web API controller blocking the main thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have an ASP.NET Web API controller that I would have *thought* would operate asynchronously. The controller is designed to sleep 20 seconds for the first request, but service any subsequent requests immediately. So my anticipated timeline would be something like:

1. Raise request 1.
2. Raise request 2.
3. Raise request 3.
4. Request 2 returns.
5. Request 3 returns.
6. Wait ~20 seconds.
7. Request 1 returns.

Instead, **no** requests return until request 1 is finished.

I can confirm (based on the debug outputs), that the entry thread and sleepy thread id are different. I've intentionally used `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to force the sleep onto a separate thread, but still the application refuses to service any new requests until that sleep has finished.

Am I missing something fundamental about how async Web API controllers really work?

---

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private static bool _firstTime = true;

    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Entry thread id: {0}. Sync: {1}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
            SynchronizationContext.Current);
        await LongWaitAsync();
        return "FOOBAR";
    }

    private Task LongWaitAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                if (_firstTime)
                {
                    _firstTime = false;
                    Debug.WriteLine("Sleepy thread id: {0}. Sync: {1}",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                        SynchronizationContext.Current);
                    Thread.Sleep(20000);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Finished sleeping");
                }
            },
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a first step, I'd mark `_firstTime` as `volatile`, to make sure that separate threads can see it changing consistently.

Comment: What web server are you using to host?

Comment: Marking `_firstTime` as `volatile` makes no difference. I've tried hosting in IIS Express 8.0 and IIS 7.5, both on Win 7 Pro.

Comment: @Snixtor - it may make no difference, but it's something that ought to be done anyway.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Duly noted. I'll admit I had to look up its meaning and it's definitely relevant to my example code.

Comment: Does Task<string> Get() call Result or Wait()? Those are blocking operations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the server, and everything to do with the client. Both Chrome and Firefox don't appear to want to send what they deem a "duplicate" request until the first one has its response. A separate "private" session of either browser will return from the second request immediately. Internet Explorer 9 doesn't seem to exhibit this behaviour.

To isolate from client implementations, I put together the following client.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = Task.Run(() => FetchData(1));
        var t2 = Task.Run(() => FetchData(2));
        var t3 = Task.Run(() => FetchData(3));

        var index = Task.WaitAny(t1, t2, t3);
        Console.WriteLine("Task {0} finished first", index + 1);

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks have finished");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void FetchData(int clientNumber)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        string data = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:61852/api/values");
        Console.WriteLine("Client {0} got data: {1}", clientNumber, data);
    }
}
```

It's output goes:

1. Client 2 got data: "FOOBAR" (within milliseconds of startup)
2. Client 3 got data: "FOOBAR"
3. Task 2 finished first
4. (long wait here)
5. Client 1 got data: "FOOBAR"
6. All tasks have finished

Comment: Thought I was going crazy. Thanks for the revelation!

Answer (score 0):

In my case here is output (it **switches** to another thread from 5 to 10):

```
Entry thread id: 5. Sync: System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext
Sleepy thread id: 10. Sync: 
Finished sleeping
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2c84) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Entry thread id: 7. Sync: System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1818) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Entry thread id: 5. Sync: System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext
The thread '<No Name>' (0xd4c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2c30) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This could be due to environment and machine running (single core) that makes the runtime decide how to run it.